# Understanding Spring4 annotation beans

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-bean

First time using Spring with annotions. I'm trying to define a singleton bean like:

```
@Bean
public ActionProducer actionProducer() {
    return new ActionProducer();
}
```

But i feel like this is not a correct way to do since returns a "new" bean each time. Should i instead define like below?

```
@Bean
public ActionProducer actionProducer() {
    if (bean==null) 
        bean=new ActionProducer();
    return bean 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `@Configuration` class, Spring will create a proxy which controls the calls to those `@Bean` methods. So if you have a `@Bean` method, which should create a singleton bean (which it does by default, if you don't specify another scope) the proxy will make sure, that the method is only called once to create the bean. All further calls are intercepted by the proxy and the already existing bean will be returned.
This way, you could even just call that bean method, if you have other beans in that class, which depend on it, without thinking about scopes, duplicate instances etc.:

```
@Bean
public AnotherClass anotherClass() {
    return new AnotherClass(actionProducer());
}
```

So don't work around the Spring functionality and just implement the method as following:

```
@Bean
public ActionProducer actionProducer() {
    return new ActionProducer();
}
```

Comment: this is very close to my issue. other bean (in the same config class) injected by actionProducer gets a different object ref.

Comment: Usually you don't get the bean instance itself injected, but a proxy instead, and every proxy is a different object, thus a different reference. But the proxies will lead to the same bean instance, if it's a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, the `@Bean` is singleton yes, and therefor returning `new ActionProducer();` is just fine. It will only be invoked by spring **once** at startup.

If `ActionProducer` is your own implementation, just annotate the class with `@Component` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Default it is treated as singleton just as in the normal annotation way or xml way. If you want other scope then you can use scope annotation on the method.

Reference
https://www.quora.com/Is-any-method-annotated-with-Bean-treated-as-Singleton-by-Spring-Framework

Answer (score 0):

The @Bean annotation let you to define a Bean into the Spring application context. 
By Default Spring creates the beans as singletons. So this code will produce a singleton in Spring context

```
@Bean
public ActionProducer actionProducer() {
    return new ActionProducer();
}
```

But you need to access the bean through the Application context

```
applicationContext.getBean("myBeanName")
```

If you need an instance of your bean for each invocation, you need to define Prototype scope. It's the same, you need to access it through the Spring application context.

```
@Bean(scope=DefaultScopes.PROTOTYPE)
public ActionProducer actionProducer() {
    return new ActionProducer();
}
```

You can see more here
http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Comment: Your link points to obsolete documentation the old Spring Java Config project. I suggest updating it to the actual Spring documentation.